# How can I stop wordpress sites on varnish with nginx and apache from loading via http?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, varnish

I have a fresh server configured with:
varinsh on port 80 (configured to redirect direct requests to 443)
nginx on port 443 (forwards to varnish)
apache on 8080 (wordpress installed here)

When I load the wordpress site all the js files are trying to load on 80 and are insecure.

Wordpress is set to override WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to https://example.com

I found an article that said I need to do this:
(nginx) proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
and then in your apache vhost configuration:
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on

Which I have done and it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about the subject a couple of years ago. Please have a look: https://feryn.eu/blog/mixed-content-and-err-too-many-redirects-in-wordpress/

Of course I'm going to put the relevant configuration out here as well.

### Nginx config

Nginx is acting as your TLS termination point, but it sends plain HTTP requests to Varnish.

You need to send an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header through Varnish and Apache, to make both of them aware of the protocol that was used.

You can add the following line to your proxy logic within your Nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

### Apache config

Apache will process this `X-Forwarded-Proto` and perform redirection if the value is not `HTTPS`.

The snippet below can be dropped in an `.htaccess` file if you want:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
Header append Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

A quick rundown of what this does:

- Check the value of the `X-Forwarded-Proto`
- Set the environment variable `HTTPS` to `ON` if `X-Forwarded-Proto` equals `HTTPS`
- Set a custom `Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto header` *(required for Varnish)*
- Do on HTTPS redirect if `HTTPS` is not `On` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` is not `HTTPS`

### What about Varnish?

By default, Varnish has no protocol awareness. You can write some VCL to make that happen, but luckily the HTTP protocol has the required semantics to make this happen using HTTP headers.

In the previous section about Apache configuration, I referred to `Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto`. This is what Varnish needs to make a distinction between HTTP & HTTPS content.

If it weren't for this `Vary` header, Varnish would cache whatever is called first, which could lead to mixed content being cached.

A `Vary` tells Varnish to create a cache variation for each value of `X-Forwarded-Proto`. This will separate HTTP content from HTTPS content and will result in the right URL scheme to be used on the cached pages.